# How can I test fetch hook of NUXT on client side?

Tags: jestjs, nuxt.js

How can I test fetch hook of NUXT on client side which is using $fetch in it? I can't find any documentation and honestly Nuxt sucks.

The only idea I have is to use

```
global.$fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({...
```

but it doesn't seem to work